# Excel combination 6

Tags: microsoft-excel

Good morning,

I am trying to do in excel all possible combination of 1 to 6 without repeating.

6!
How can I list the 720 possibilities

Thank you,
examples
123456
132456
654321

Comment: [Here is the solution in C.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506078/fast-permutation-number-permutation-mapping-algorithms/1506337#1506337) Why do you want to use Excel? Would it suffice to take the output and paste it as 720 rows, or is there some dynamic aspect of the worksheet you'll need?

Comment: You could apply Aron Foster's example in VBA to keep it within Excel if you'd like.

Comment: Have you put any effort at all into figuring this out yourself?

Comment: What code do you have so far? What exactly works and doesn't?

Comment: cool math quesion, unhold please!

Comment: @STTR - If only this was a math site.

Answer (score 2):

This macro is simple, but slow:

```
Sub Pickz()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    Dim Z As Long
    Z = 1
    For i = 1 To 6
    For j = 1 To 6
    For k = 1 To 6
    For l = 1 To 6
    For m = 1 To 6
    For n = 1 To 6
    If Zort(i, j, k, l, m, n) Then
        Cells(Z, 1) = i & j & k & l & m & n
        Z = Z + 1
    End If
    Next n
    Next m
    Next l
    Next k
    Next j
    Next i
End Sub

Function Zort(i, j, k, l, m, n) As Boolean
    Dim c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    Zort = True
    On Error Resume Next
    c.Add i, CStr(i)
    c.Add j, CStr(j)
    c.Add k, CStr(k)
    c.Add l, CStr(l)
    c.Add m, CStr(m)
    c.Add n, CStr(n)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Else
        Zort = False
        Err.Number = 0
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: @fixer1234  Give the code a try......... **ZORT()** reduces the output to 720 samples.

Comment: Copy the **Zort()** function from my post along with the **Pickz()** sub.

Comment: I'm way too rusty on VBA.  Is a property of a collection that all members must be unique?

Comment: Yes....if you use it with a **key** ( the *CStr()* part) duplicates are rejected

Comment: Thanks for the education.  +1.  If you're ambitious, including a short explanation of how it works would make it a great general answer.